# How do I re run the function in my Simon game?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty confident that I have the basic logic behind my Simon game. However, I'm having issues in going to the next round. I have attempted to use an if statement and while loop but neither have worked. How should I proceed?

A brief explanation: gameColors is an array that has all the random colors that will be played out in an increasing number over several rounds. The variable sequencelength is used to increase the counter used in the user input function, whereas the variable sequenceLengthInv is the opposite of that, subtracted from gameColors.length to get sequenceLength.

random sequence displays the random sequence of colors up to the sequenceLength value.

JS:

```
if (sequenceLengthInv >= 0) {
   // have the game play the random sequence of colors
   for (var i = 0; i < gameColors.length - sequenceLengthInv; i++) {
       randomSequence();
   }


   //listens for the user's input
   for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
       userInput();
   }
sequenceLength++;
sequenceLengthInv--;
}
```

Comment: What were your attempts?

Comment: I attempted to run a do...while loop but it was still giving me issues. If I did a while loop it crashed the browser. Would I do something similar to my randomSequence function? Here it is for reference.

`function randomSequence() {
    setTimeout(colorSequenceOn, timeInterval, i);
    setTimeout(colorSequenceOff, timeInterval + 333, i);
    timeInterval += 666;
}`

In addition, here is the link to the Github repo. https://github.com/rise-and-shane93

Comment: What does `userInput` do when the user guesses wrong?

Comment: Here is the userInput function for reference:

`function userInput() {
    color[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var result = this.getAttribute('class');
        if (result.includes(gameColors[counter]) && counter < sequenceLength) {
            console.log('correct');
            counter++;
        } else {
            alert('incorrect! You have lost the game!');
        }
    });
}`

For now I just have a console.log stating that it is incorrect but also if they click more times than the counter (if the sequence flashed 5 colors, the user clicks 5 colors).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for` loops and using `throw`/`reject` & `catch` (or `break`). Also, `Promise`s may be useful here.

```
async function playGame(availableColors, minColors, maxColors) {
    await wait(333);

    var colors = Array.from({ length: maxColors }, () => randomChoice(availableColors));

    try {
        for (var i = minColors; i <= maxColors; i++) {
            console.log(colors.slice(0, i));
            await playRound(colors.slice(0, i));
        }

        alert('You win!');
    } catch (e) {
        if(e !== undefined) {
            throw e;
        }

        alert('You lose!');
    }
}
```

My modified (and now commented) code is available here: https://repl.it/@solly_ucko/InconsequentialRoastedMonitor.

Comment: So when I did that the simon game put out over 10 random colors when it should've been 5 to start out with

Comment: Are you referring to the length of `gameColors`, the length of `color` or how many are displayed?

Comment: how many colors are displayed. The length of the `gameColors` array is 10 but more than 10 colors are flashing on the screen.

Comment: @ShaneHarper I see what you mean. I'm taking a look.

Comment: @ShaneHarper Here's where I'm trying stuff out: https://repl.it/@solly_ucko/InconsequentialRoastedMonitor. I think you'll probably want to use callback chaining instead of a while loop.

Comment: @ShaneHarper I think I got it to work, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @Solly that would be great haha - that advanced Javascript is having my head spin

Comment: @ShaneHarper I'll add comments to the code when I get a chance, but I'm also happy to answer questions if you have any.

Comment: @ShaneHarper I've added comments; let me know if you still have any questions.